# ds3.js Color range.

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a sunburst where each category is a different color. I can get up to 20 colors to work, but I have more than 20 variables. So, I would like to have more colors to choose from. I am not at all adept in Java Script and any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the current code that I am running in R that yields the 20 colors.

```
browsable(tagList(
  html_dependency_vue(),
  tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/d3"),
  tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/d2b@0.5.1/build/d2b.js"),
  tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/vue-d2b"),
  tags$script(src = "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"),
  tags$div(
    id = "app",
    style = "height:400px",
    tag(
      "sunburst-chart",
      list(":data" = "sunburstChartData", ":config" = "sunburstChartConfig")
    )),
  tags$script(HTML(
    sprintf(
"
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
  'sunburst-chart': vued2b.ChartSunburst
},
  data: {
    sunburstChartData: %s,
    sunburstChartConfig: function(chart) {
      var color = d3.scale.category20();
      chart.label(function(d){return d.name});
      //chart.sunburst().size(function(d){return d.x});
      chart.color(function(d){return color(d.name);})
      //chart.color(function(d){return typeof(d.color) === 'undefined' ? '#BBB' : d.color; })
      }
  }
})
",
      hier_json1
    )
  ))
))
```

Reading another post here on stack overflow it looks like I need to make a list of the colors I want and putting that into the source code for the 20 colors shown below.

```
d3.scale.category30 = function() {
    return d3.scale.ordinal().range(d3_category30);
};
var d3_category30 = [
  0x1f77b4, 0xaec7e8,
  0xff7f0e, 0xffbb78,
  0x2ca02c, 0x98df8a,
  0xd62728, 0xff9896,
  0x9467bd, 0xc5b0d5,
  0x8c564b, 0xc49c94,
  0xe377c2, 0xf7b6d2,
  0x7f7f7f, 0xc7c7c7,
  0xbcbd22, 0xdbdb8d,
  0x17becf, 0x9edae5
].map(d3_rgbString);
```

Again I do not know java script very well and have not been able to get this to work. I would be grateful for any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code throws an error for me here that says d3_rgbString is undefined, its defined in the source code and intended to be use only internally for certain methods of d3. But, you are over-complicating, range is an array (of colors in this case). You have an array - but not of colors, of numbers, d3_rgbString is intended to convert those numbers to strings that can be used to color elements (expanding the code here):

```
colorArray.map(function(color) { return d3_rgbString(color); })
```

*Where `colorArray` is the array of numerical color values.*

This gives us a new array with `.map` of color strings. (Newer versions of d3 actually take a different approach with long strings with d3 then splitting the strings into substrings representing each color).

The simplest solution is then to convert your numbers into strings, the easiest way is to remove the `0x` and add a `#`, while placing each color in quotes - this allows you to drop the `.map()`. If you have to come up with the colors anyways, typing `"#123456"` will take about as much time as `0x123456` and you don't need to come up with a function to convert your number to a string (though I imagine there are many posts on this site about getting RGB strings from numbers to ease your way if you want to replace d3_rgbString with a function of your own). *An advantage of using color strings that don't need adjustment is you could then easily use standard css color names too*

So, just feed an array of `n` colors to `d3.scale.ordinal().range()` and you'll have a scale with an arbitrary number of colors:

```js
var d3_category30 = [
  "#1f77b4", "#aec7e8",
  "#ff7f0e", "#ffbb78",
  "#2ca02c", "#98df8a",
  "#d62728", "#ff9896",
  "#9467bd", "#c5b0d5",
  "#e377c2", "#f7b6d2",
  "#7f7f7f", "#c7c7c7",
  "#bcbd22", "#dbdb8d",
  "#17becf", "#9edae5",
  "salmon","lightsalmon",
  "lightsteelblue","steelblue",
  "yellow","orange",
  "#cccccc","#dddddd","#eee","#aaa",
  "#123456","black"
];

d3.scale.category30 = function() {
    return d3.scale.ordinal().range(d3_category30);
};

var color = d3.scale.category30();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500);

svg.selectAll("circle")
 .data(d3.range(30))
 .enter()
 .append("circle")
 .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return i%15 * 20 + 20; })
 .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return Math.floor(i/15) * 20 + 20 })
 .attr("r", 10)
 .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d); })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Andrew thank you for this answer. I am still trying to understand how this is working. I went into the source and searched for category30 but I couldn't find the code in there. Does the above code you wrote not have to be in the source? Where would the correct placement of the code be in my example code. I apologize for all these questions, I am really new to javascript.

Comment: No, the code is not placed in the source ideally - you could make a .js file with the code you see here. It is probably easiest to place it at the beginning of `function(chart) { `, but you could also use: `var color =  d3.scale.ordinal().range(["color","color","color","color",....]);`